# CSS3 Progress bar jumps

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/JgVFm/1/

And basically the progress bar goes up to 100% and then jumps back to 50%.

The bar should actually go up to 50% and just stop there. Any help with achieving this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ps. this is using css3 and webkit elements so will only work in chrome and safari.

Comment: One question: Did you write this code? The answer looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: nope, it was a mashup of various examples. I'd also been on my comp for too many hours to count, even simple things are taking some time. I think time for some sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the final width?

```
@-webkit-keyframes progress
{
    0%   { width: 36px;  }
    100% { width: 121px; }
}
```

Comment: That does seem to fix the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JgVFm/5/ I wonder if the OP is wanting to represent both though, a 100% while only actually getting to 50%?

Comment: perfect that's exactly what I want. I am going to use some php to change the width, according where I want the bar to finish. Thanks :)

Comment: I was just about to say "Although I don't think it's possible in CSS to do that", and I see the OP has said this *is* what they wanted.

Comment: I'm going to put @-webkit-keyframes progress
{
    0%   { width: 36px;  }
    100% { width: 121px; }
} of the css in php and calcualte the width I need. unless there is a better way?

Comment: I don't see any better way, but please note I'm not particularly good at CSS.